# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, encryption, char

I'm decrypting a message and got this error from String.fromCharCodes

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid character (at character 1)
```

I use this to encrypt my message :

```
/// Encrypting String
String encrypt(String plaintext, RSAPublicKey publicKey) {
  var cipher = new RSAEngine()
    ..init(true, new PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(publicKey));

  var utf8Encoded = utf8.encode(plaintext);

  var encoded64 = base64.encode(utf8Encoded);

  var cipherText = cipher.process(new Uint8List.fromList(encoded64.codeUnits));

  var result = String.fromCharCodes(cipherText);

  return result;
}
```

and then

```
/// Decrypting String
String decrypt(String ciphertext, RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {
  var cipher = new RSAEngine()
    ..init(false, new PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(privateKey));

  var decrypted = cipher.process(new Uint8List.fromList(ciphertext.codeUnits));

  var encoded64 = String.fromCharCodes(decrypted);

  var decoded64 = utf8.decode(base64.decode(encoded64));

  return decoded64;
}
```

I have indeed invalid char in encoded64 during decryption, but i don't understand why.

I don't get why i got the issue, or how to prevent/avoid it. Can someone help me here?

Comment: what package are you using for this?

Comment: pointycastle, i juste saw that ciphertext.codeUnits contains UTF-16 btw. I got the error during decryption

Comment: The encoding used in `encrypt()` is an inefficient (and unnecessary) combination of UTF-8, Base64 and Latin1. Use for encryption instead: 1. UTF-8 encoding of the plaintext 2. encryption 3. Base64 encoding of the ciphertext. And in `decrypt()`: 1. Base64 decoding of the ciphertext 2. decryption 3. UTF-8 decoding of the decrypted data.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Topaco, i'll try that today and let you know of the result

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have time to come back to this thread, but kudos to @Topaco, his solution is the right one to my question.

(in the comment of the question)

I don't know how to give him credit, so if someone can point it out in a comment that's great!

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue, In my case issue was related to string which I pass for decryption. Please check your encrypted text which you are passing is it properly encrypted (without any white space) or not.

Comment: as you can see, i provided my encryption function with
`var cipherText = cipher.process(Uint8List.fromList(encoded64.codeUnits));`
so it can't be that..